# Maven Assembly plugin fileMode not working on fileSet

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Maven Assembly plugin is not applying fileMode on some fileSets. On some fileSets it works on some others it doesn't.

This is the assembly.xml:

```
<assembly>
<id>
    assembly
</id>
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>src/main/resources/config/
        </directory>
        <outputDirectory>/config/</outputDirectory>
        <excludes>
        </excludes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>src/main/resources/excel/
        </directory>
        <outputDirectory>/excel/</outputDirectory>
        <fileMode>0666</fileMode> <!-- WORKING -->
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>src/main/resources/logs/
        </directory>
        <outputDirectory>/logs/</outputDirectory>
        <fileMode>0666</fileMode> <!-- NOT WORKING -->
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>src/main/resources/sh/</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/sh/</outputDirectory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>*.formatted</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <lineEnding>unix</lineEnding>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

All the files decompressed under the excel/ folder have -rw-rw-rw- permission which is 0666. All the files decompressed under the logs/ folder have -rwxrwxr-x which is not 0666.

This is the pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <id>assembly</id>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Maybe related https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-238 . Does it happen with `tar.gz` too?

Comment: I don't know. Artifact is deployed in an enterprise environment which decompresses the zip, I can't test with the .gz.

Answer (score 1):

This is a regression and a known bug that somehow keeps rearing its ugly head. The [latest bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/MASSEMBLY/issues/MASSEMBLY-941?filter=allopenissues) claims it started after 3.1.1, but clearly from your report there were already problems.

It would be helpful to go to the ticket on the [Maven Assembly Jira ticket tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY) and add comments so that engineers will know this isn't just a one-off. I also experienced the issue.

Related tickets (re regression):

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-238
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-379
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-580
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-852